# Do it fires a database query when we do a query on a Active Record object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

What happens when we give a query on a Active record object? like

`users = User.where(:country => 'some country')
 users.size   => 20
 users.where(:user_type => admin)`

when we give a query on users(suppose it contains 20 users), what happens does it fires a query in the database to fetch all the users who are admin or it only looks into the users object to get all the user who are admin.

Comment: yes you can check it in log file ``

Comment: Normally when such Active Record query is fired,it generates an `SQL` query in the log file.You can check the latest generated query by giving `tail -f log/development.log`

Answer (score 0):

When you do something like this, it will fire another SQL query with an `AND` expression in the end of the first one.

**First Query**

```
SELECT users.* FROM users WHERE users.country = 'some country'
```

**Second one**

```
SELECT users.* FROM users WHERE users.country = 'some country' AND users.user_type = 'admin'
```

P.S.: This kind of stuff can be easily tested on `rails console`.

Comment: Just to clarify if the first query has already been executed then .size will just determine the length of the collection otherwise it will do a count call on the db

Comment: `.size` is an array method, so it will just look at the collection length. If you use `.count`, then it will look at the db again.